# global declaration of NSTextField array

Tags: swift, global

I want to declare a global array of NSTextFields, but "Class ViewController has no initializers." Yes, global, but static.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TextField01: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var TextField02: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var TextField03: NSTextField!
    
    var fieldArray: [NSTextField]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fieldArray = [TextField01, TextField02, TextField03]
        
    }
```

I thought that the problem was the compiler not knowing about the main storyboard; that's why I didn't assign values to my fieldArray. It would appear that I need to declare (initialize?) fieldArray in some other way.

Comment: `fieldArray` has to have a value when you declare it (or one sit in the initializer). You can change your line to: `var fieldArray: [NSTextField] = []`

Comment: This isn't `global`, by the way -- it's an instance variable.

Comment: The code you posted is perfectly fine if you make one tiny change. Add an `!` to the end of the `var fieldArray: [NSTextField]` line (just like the outlets). Just make sure you make no attempt to access `fieldArray` before `viewDidLoad` runs.